# How to insert one record after every log record in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have a PostgreSQL table that store logs data with each row is one log and fields are `logname, start, end`. I want to visualize the logs, and due to a limit of Grafana the visualize tool I choose, I feel the need to insert one new record with stimestamp one second after each log, let's say with logname 'Idle'. For better explanation:

| Start | Logname | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | log-in | 10:00:01 |
| 10:30:00 | call | 11:00:00 |
| 10:55:00 | some action (still in call) | 11:05:00 |

Then I want to manually add logname 'Idle' one second after each available logs

| Start | Logname | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | log-in | 10:00:01 |
| **10:30:02 (1 second after the end time of the previous log)** | **idle** | **10:30:03** |
| 10:30:00 | call | 11:00:00 |
| 10:55:00 | some action | 11:05:00 |
| **11:05:01 (1 second after)** | **idle** | **11:05:01** |

I think of manually calculating each row and then inserting them, but how should I do it in terms of a PostgreSQL query?

**Update**
Thanks to Akina & dwhitemv, I see it's illogical to insert a new record after *every* available record. Instead, the question should be **inserting a new record into time ranges only if there are no available records or overlapping records.** Aside from inserting, a new problem is how to check if there is a record(s) in the time range. I updated the tables above. I feel this makes it complicated since using `NOT EXISTS` & `ON CONFLICT` can't really check if records exist between 11:00 and 11:05?

Comment: So you want to find all the time ranges where _no_ record exists?

Comment: Oh, you can put it that way. At first, I intended to insert a new **Idle** record after *every* record, which will double the size of the table, regardless of whether there is already a log record in the next 1 second or even a time overlap of 2 log records. Now look at Akina's and your responses, it doesn't make sense to insert an **Idle** to the time ranges where records already exist. Post updated to clarify.

Comment: I read you right then. Your question falls into the class of problems known as gaps and islands. I have another solution in my head I will try to complete & submit. Another thought I had was to use a view to generate the idle ranges on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```sql
INSERT INTO logs (Start, Logname, End)
SELECT End + INTERVAL '1 second',       -- previous End + 1 second
       'Idle',                          -- static literal value
       End + INTERVAL '2 second'        -- current Start + 1 second
FROM logs
ON CONFLICT (Start) DO NOTHING;         -- skip insertion if the row exists already
```

The query does not check the overlapping which may occur if 2 source rows are adjacent (End_1 = Start_2). If you'd check this then use according WHERE NOT EXISTS instread of ON CONFLICT.

Comment: can you explain more about how to use WHERE NOT EXISTS? Usually, it's *WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ....)* & I'm not sure how to achieve it in my case

Comment: @Elly INSERT INTO logs SELECT .. FROM logs t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM logs t2 WHERE {t1&t2 overlapping detection} ).

Comment: Thank you! I combined your solution and another solution I found, and although I haven't done a complete sanity check yet, seems like it works.